# How can I compile a fltk program using g++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, g++, compilation, fltk

How can I compile a fltk program using g++ in Ubuntu?

Straight-forward question. I've been searching for and trying many things for a couple hours now. Some of the examples I have seen require X11R6, but I can only find X11 on my computer. If anyone can tell me, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sterling, all you need to know is on this page: http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal.
 cd to the directory that has your text file named file22.cpp or what ever you saved as.
 Type:

g++ `fltk-config --cxxflags` file22.cpp  `fltk-config --ldflags` -o go

To run type:

./go

I have used this with Ubuntu 8 to Ubuntu 12.10 and Mint 13 and Mint 14.
 Which are all Linux.

Files22.cxx is used if the GUI Fluid is used.

g++ `fltk-config --cxxflags` file22.cxx `fltk-config --ldflags` -o go

Answer (score 0):

`X11` that you have *is* `X11R6`.

You'll get a better answer if you tell us what your *actual* problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ `fltk-config --cxxflags` file22.cpp `fltk-config --ldflags` -o go
```

don't forget the backtiks!;)